# Schedule Cron job to trigger the 1st day of month -- except if it's Sunday

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I want it fire a job once on every 1st day in a every month that should be any week day.But if it is sunday on 1st do not fire the job just postpone it to fire at 2nd day and immediately terminate schedule.
Again do the same process of scheduling for next months also.?

Below is the code to schedule it for every 55 seconds for testing envrironment and how about the destroy method?

```
QuartzPlugin.java

public class QuartzPlugin implements PlugIn {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
    @Override
    public void init(ActionServlet servlet, ModuleConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // define the job and tie it to our MyJob class
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SchedulerJob.class).withIdentity("anyJobName", "group1").build();
        try {
            // Cron Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 55 secs
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("anyTriggerName", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/55 * * * * ?"))
                    //Every 1 minute "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"
                    // Every 55 Sec "0/55 * * * * ?"
                    // Every 5 Sec "0/5 * * * * ?"
                    // Every month 1st day "0 10 1-7 * *"
                    .build();
            // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
            Scheduler   scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            // and start it off
            scheduler.start();
            // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

SchedularJob.java

public class SchedulerJob implements Job {

    private ArrayList mapList = new ArrayList();
    private DAO dao = new DAO();
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    private FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        String dirpath = System.getProperty("user.dir").replaceAll("bin", "") + "webapps/it_email/sent/email_"
        + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
        String genStatus = generateExcel(dirpath);
        System.out.println("genStatus::" + genStatus);
        if (genStatus.equals("Y")) {
            String text = "Please find attached case list dated "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date()) + "."
                    + "\n\n Microsoft Excel is required to open this attachment.\n\n"
                    + "Registrar Judicial,High Court of Judicature at Hyderabad.\n\n"
                    + "This email is System  generated. Please do not reply to this email ID.\n\n "
                    + "Disclaimer:The NIC/High Court is not responsible for non-delivery of emails.";
            String subject = "HIGH COURT:Availability of Case Data.";
            String to = "ajaythakur2014@gmail.com";
            String filetype = ".xls";
            sendEmail(to, subject, text, dirpath, filetype);
            System.out.println("For every 55 secs");
        }
    }
```

When the above code is run i sporadically get the 
Oracle 9i Production Environment : `IO Exception : The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`
i guess creating more no of new connections every 55 seconds.

Comment: What code have you tried to schedule the job the first day of every month? And what modifications have you tried to avoid it running on Sunday? The code you included is for a job scheduled to run every 55 seconds, which has nothing to do with your question. Please include the code for your actual problem.

Comment: I did it try to work with some intervals but my concern is to start and stop at particular time period.

Comment: Still no code related to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Could be useful this link ,where there is the official documentation :[MonthlyTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/MonthlyTrigger.html)